# Изначальный размер списка ArrayList

Tags: java

Недавно узнал что  ArrayList capacity  по умолчанию  на 10 элементов. Но вот не могу понять почему при выводе в консоль пустого списка выдается 0? По идее же должно выдаваться 10?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: Capacity это количество ячеек в массиве, обёрткой над которым является list, size выдаёт количество заполненных ячеек.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/159557/#:~:text=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20ArrayList%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%2080%20(144)%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `size()` показывает сколько элементов в списке, а не ёмкость хранилища. Образно говоря, если вы в трёхлитровую банку налёте литр воды и поставите её на весы, вы увидите вес около килограмма, а не трёх.

Comment: На собеседовании тимлид мне сказал что размер будет 10. пытаюсь понять почему. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Delembech либо вы его не так поняли, либо не стоит идти в компанию с такими тимлидами.

Comment: вопрос был сформирован именно так. Это и ввело меня в ступор, и первым делом что я сделал дабы понять что он имел ввиду попробовал сам